# Using K- Protoypes in R

Tags: r

I'd like to try the K prototypes for my data, but when I use the code:

```
kpres <- kproto(#name of data", "number of cluster", lambda = xx)
```

I get the following mistake:

> Error in Ops.data.frame(x[, j], rep(protos[i, j], nrows)) :    list of
>   length 3994 not meaningful

Does somebody know how to fix it?

Thanks!!

Comment: See [mcve] for info on how to ask a question.

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It doesn't look like you are calling the function like it appears in the documentation at all. Are you following some guide?

Comment: Sure, my guide is the following link         https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/clustMixType/clustMixType.pdf

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert the data into a `dataframe` first and then pass it to kproto.

For example:

```
data<- as.data.frame(data)
kpres <- kproto(data, "number of cluster", lambda = xx)
```